# type narrowing for return type conditional on null parameter

Tags: typescript, null, conditional-types

I'd like my function to return null if a certain parameter is null. I believe the correct return type conditional on the parameter is `null extends typeof param ? null : string`. However, when I return `null` conditionally on the parameter being `null`, TS is not happy with me:

```
export const foo1 = (param: string | null): null extends typeof param ? null : string => {
  if(typeof param === null) {
    return null
  }
  // error: Type '""' is not assignable to type 'null'.(2322)
  return "";
}
```

What should I compare `param` with when I return `null` so that TS is happy when I otherwise return a `string`?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGYQgRjgXjgAoBLAEwC450oTkBzOAHzmQFcAbDgSiva7igYwZGVRwYATzDAIGOOTgB+Vpw5wqNOo3wA+OAG8AUHAUYiUmXIVkC+Qvx6GTpuFGAw2UZKq4uAvi4A9EGCUFDQVAAq0sBwAOQARInxCuLIEPAAhqioJPTIWQBGHHEwEBKxCY7xAHREAEwAzA0N3C7unt5wyQDcRoFGoJCwiCjocFgQDQTE5JowtAzMvjx8aoIgwqLilrLyiiqOGtSL2gT6xqYhYRFQ0QAWcaUYMAC0D1mi1ORx1l8JOjoL4IfapYbuXIkFBwAC2bAmRT+8j2CS+kniABo4ACIEUAFbABDwVHQHGVGRwMBZKBZWEeYBQerNACsAA52qYSOY9tZFECYCD9qtuM5XG4PF4fI4AsFQoy7tEqkkUmlWJkcVCCsVShIKqj4jVmS02h1Jd0+gMjEA)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that using any conditional return types is valid TS unless you specify it, but if so, I can't imagine it would be good practice unless you have a very specific scenario where it is necessary.

You can change the `null extends typeof param ? null : string` to `string | null` instead. This will allow you to return either null or string however you feel like.

```
export const foo1 = (id: string | null): string | null => {
  if(typeof id === null) {
    return null
  }
  
  return "";
}
```

Comment: But I want clients to know when they don't pass null that they won't get a null back.

Comment: @NateGlenn That seems really unnecessary, in my opinion. Why not just make it only accept a string as a parameter? Then your clients will automatically know that they can't use the function unless they provide it with a non-null parameter. Making it accept a null to return a null immediately is redundant and likely leads to confusion. Whether the value the client decides to provide is null or not shouldn't be of your concern if your function only works with a non-null value. Your client should be responsible for ensuring the function is only called with a valid value.

Comment: it's a fair point, but in this case I happen to want to encapsulate the if-null-then-null logic in the function. It happens to be a utility function which is used throughout a large codebase in contexts where adding an if statement would ruin the brevity, anyway. Through your comments I was able to find a duplicate question on SO (marked above), and it seems to me that it's not quite possible to do what I want in TS right now.